# Question about the use of Dropdown React in semantic-ui-react

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, semantic-ui-react

I want to build adropdown list using the Dropdown component from **semantic-ui-react**
I followed the code hosted here : https://codesandbox.io/s/50xzvqrwxn?module=/example.js, which seems to be pretty good.
Here is the following result I have when I put it in my code :
[image]

And here is my render function :

```
render() {
return (
  <div className="NewNote">
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <FormGroup controlId="content">
        <FormControl
          placeholder="Enter your comment on file here..."
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.state.content}
          componentClass="textarea"
        />
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup controlId="file">
        <ControlLabel>Attachment</ControlLabel>
        <FormControl onChange={this.handleFileChange} type="file" />
      </FormGroup>

      <FormGroup>
        <ControlLabel>Select file category</ControlLabel>
      </FormGroup>

      <Dropdown text='File'>
        <Dropdown.Menu>
          <Dropdown.Item text='New' />
          <Dropdown.Item text='Open...' description='ctrl + o' />
          <Dropdown.Item text='Save as...' description='ctrl + s' />
          <Dropdown.Item text='Rename' description='ctrl + r' />
          <Dropdown.Item text='Make a copy' />
          <Dropdown.Item icon='folder' text='Move to folder' />
          <Dropdown.Item icon='trash' text='Move to trash' />
          <Dropdown.Divider />
          <Dropdown.Item text='Download As...' />
          <Dropdown.Item text='Publish To Web' />
          <Dropdown.Item text='E-mail Collaborators' />
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>

      <LoaderButton
        block
        bsStyle="primary"
        bsSize="large"
        disabled={!this.validateForm()}
        type="submit"
        isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
        text="Create"
        loadingText="Creating…"
      />
    </form>
  </div>
);
}
```

Does someone have an idea about this problem ?

Comment: did you import the relative styling that the dropdown needs?

Comment: I've import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css', but it says it can resolve the name...

Comment: Well sounds like you don't have the css.. did you import it like the docs recommend? `import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'`